# unicode-escaping with a standard Unix tool

Tags: python, javascript, unicode

I have cooked up the following python script, it does 1 thing and it does it well. It does, whatever Unicode magic `unicode-escape` does in python3 to some text.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

text = sys.stdin.read()

new_text = text.encode('unicode-escape').decode()

sys.stdout.write(new_text)
```

However, it feels like there's probably a built in unix tool or one I could install easily that would also do the job with out the need for "a whole python". I've been trying out `uconv` but so far none of the spaghetti I have thrown at the wall has worked.

It would be even better if this was a tool that just came preinstalled on MacOS. But being able to install it with `brew` would be almost as good.

Is there a standard unix tool I can use to get the same results?

If you are interested in a little more context, I'm embedding an Elm app in a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API), which is inside of a [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components). The way I've figured out how to embed the JavaScript for the web worker requires this Unicode escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the commands from the article
[How to convert Unicode string to Unicode escape sequences?-bash](https://www.appsloveworld.com/bash/100/104/how-to-convert-unicode-string-to-unicode-escape-sequences)

The article came up with this pipe :

```
printf '文' | iconv -t UTF16BE | od -t x2 -An -v --endian=big | sed 's/ /\\u/g'
```